# Adding a scrollbar to multiple frames in tkinter in python 3.7x

Tags: tkinter

I am making a quiz software for myself and while making it when I crossed 400 lines of code I stumbled across a problem that is I have a screen in which I have to select the topics from various subjects and the number of topics I have is quite large they are like 30 in each subject. So it is not possible to accommodate them all into a single screen, so I decided to add scrollbars to each frame so that I could do so, I took reference from [***here***](https://youtu.be/0WafQCaok6g), and there John Elder Sir told that this could be done in the following steps:

1. Make a mainframe
2. Add canvas to the frame(**As canvas is the only tkinter widget which can be scrolled**)
3. Add scrollbar to the canvas
4. Add content frame to the canvas
5. Configure the scrollbar to control the change in the content frame

So I tried to do the same but for my program:

Initially, my screen looked like this:
[***I started here***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhWaY.png)

And my code was like below[*I am pasting only the region that I played with*]:

```
for sub in subjects:
              
        
        chapterwindow=LabelFrame(currentFrame,text=sub, width=500, height=500)
        subFile=open(sub+'.txt','r')
        store=subFile.read()
        store=store.split('\n')
        
        
        
        subFile.close()
        for i in store:
            if len(i)>0:
                cbVariables[i]=StringVar()
                a=Checkbutton(chapterwindow,text=i,variable=cbVariables[i],onvalue=1,offvalue=0,command=lambda :addTopic())
                a.pack()
                a.deselect()
        chapterwindow.pack(side='right',padx=30)
```

Then I did the same as was told to do but applied the whole in the loop I used in the above code

```
for sub in subjects:
        key_frame=(currentFrame)
        key_frame.pack(fill='both',expand=1)
        
        my_canvas=Canvas(key_frame)

        my_canvas.pack(side='left',fill=BOTH,expand=1)

        #Adding a scrollbar
        my_scrollbar=ttk.Scrollbar(key_frame,orient=VERTICAL,command=my_canvas.yview)
        my_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)

        #Configure the canvas
        my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)
        my_canvas.bind('<Configure>',lambda e:my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox('all')))      
            
        chapterwindow=LabelFrame(my_canvas,text=sub, width=500, height=500)
        my_canvas.create_window((0,0),window=chapterwindow,anchor='nw')
    
        subFile=open(sub+'.txt','r')
        store=subFile.read()
        store=store.split('\n')
        
        
        
        subFile.close()
        for i in store:
            if len(i)>0:
                cbVariables[i]=StringVar()
                a=Checkbutton(chapterwindow,text=i,variable=cbVariables[i],onvalue=1,offvalue=0,command=lambda :addTopic())
                a.pack()
                a.deselect()
        chapterwindow.pack(side='right',padx=30)
```

But the result was not as I expected:
[This was the result, all the scrollbars stood separate and the frames did too, also only one scroll bar is active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXFYe.png)

So my questions are:

1. **How can I attatch the scrollbars to the individual frame without having this mess**
2. **How can I help you by giving more information about the whole code**

> Here is the link to the whole code https://www.ppaste.org/8tmuyApqT

Comment: welcome to SO, Rudraansh. It would be better to provide us a [minimal reproducible example](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to work with. You can either edit your question to include an MCVE (same as above) or use a code sharing service like ppaste or dpaste.

Comment: Ok Thanks, I flagged your comment by mistake how can I undo it ???@PSSolanki sir

Comment: I don't know. try clicking on flag icon again.

Comment: Maybe it can be clicked only once. I am so sorry, by the way, It is really difficult to reproduce the problem  as an MCVE but I can give the whole code(400 lines ), if you don't mind through dpaste or ppaste

Comment: Share the code through ppaste/dpaste, share the link and also include the link in your question as well.

Comment: here is the link to the whole code, https://www.ppaste.org/8tmuyApqT, @PSSolanki sir